How to search for matching values from a dataframe to a different dataframe containing semicolon-delimited data?
I have two dataframes with all data as text/string.
df1 with data as:

and df2 with data as :

I would like to highlight the matching values in yellow and render df2 as an html with the highlighted text.

How can I go about this?
I have tried using str.split(;) to split the dataframe into lists but the code is not working.
